# Get store state in js file

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am looking the solution for getting all state store in .js file (no .ts) via ngrx Angular.

It is not component. So probably using selector for all state is not a good solution...

I am tried by `import {store} from '@ngrx/store';`... but not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution is to store your state somewhere, and in your .js file get the state from that somewhere

For example you could do this with localstorage or sessionstorage

To automatically store your state, you can use a meta reducer (doc here : https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers)